# JavaScript function won't load html pages

Tags: javascript, css, html, ipad

I have been struggling with this for two days. This JavaScript should load my home.html page upon load and then my other pages when the links are clicked. Even the home page won't load. It doesn't make any sense to me why nothing is loading. Can anyone see where my mistake is?

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        setOrientationListener();

    changePage('home.html?v=1');

    $('nav a').on('click', function(){
        $('nav a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    })
});

function changePage(fileName){

    $('.content_container').animate({opacity:0}, 500, function(){
        $('.content_loading_container').load('assets/content/'+fileName, function(){
            $('.content_container').delay(250).animate({opacity:1}, 500);
        });
    });
}
```

CSS:

```
/* Global Styles */
body { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 16px; background-    color: #ddd;}


/* Global Layout */

header  { display: block; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 55px;     background: url(../images/template/background_banner.jpg?v=1) no-repeat 0px 0px; -webkit-box-    shadow: 0px 5px 4px rgba(122,122,122,0.8); box-shadow: 0px 5px 4px rgba(122,122,122,0.8); }
article { display: block; position: absolute; top: 55px; left: 0px; background:     url(../images/template/background_content.jpg?v=1) repeat-x 0px 0px; }
article .content_container { position: absolute; bottom: 30px; left: 0px; background: none; }
article .content_container .content_loading_container { position: absolute; bottom: 30px;     padding: 40px 20px 0px 40px; }
footer  { display: block; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; height: 30px;   background-color: #ffb91d; }
nav { position: absolute; top: 70px; left: 25px; }

.banner_logo { position: absolute; top:0px; left:0px; }

.engine_image, .commercial_image, .military_image, .uav_image  { -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in-out; }

.engine_image { position: absolute; -webkit-transform: translate3d(1400px,200px,0px); }
.commercial_image   { position: absolute; -webkit-transform: translate3d(-500px,1400px,0px); }
.military_image   { position: absolute; -webkit-transform: translate3d(-700px,200px,0px); }
.uav_image  { position: absolute; -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px,-800px,0px); }

.icon { -webkit-border-radius:15px; -webkit-box-shadow:0 5px 10px 0 #aaaaaa; }

nav a { padding: 5px 5px 15px 5px; background-color:#ffffff; background-position: 0px 0px; background-repeat; }
nav a.selected { background-color: #ffb91d; repeat-y 0px 0px; }

/* Page-specific Style and Layout */
.page.home article .content_container { background: url(../images/template/background_content_home.jpg?v=1) no-repeat 0px 0px; }

/* Orientation-specific Layout - Landscape */
.page.landscape  { position: relative; width: 1024px; height: 748px; overflow: hidden; }
.page.landscape header  { width: 1024px; }
.page.landscape article { width: 1024px; height: 663px; }
.page.landscape footer  { width: 1024px; }

.page.landscape article .content_container { width: 1024px; height: 663px; }

.page.landscape.home .engine_image { position: absolute; -webkit-transform: translate3d(800px,150px,0px); }
.page.landscape.home .commercial_image   { position: absolute; -webkit-transform: translate3d(600px,500px,0px); }
.page.landscape.home .military_image   { position: absolute; -webkit-transform: translate3d(700px,375px,0px); }
.page.landscape.home .uav_image  { position: absolute; -webkit-transform: translate3d(700px,210px,0px); }

/* Orientation-specific Layout - Portrait */
.page.portrait { position: relative; width: 768px; height: 1004px; overflow: hidden; }
.page.portrait header  { width: 768px; }
.page.portrait article { width: 768px; height: 919px; }
.page.portrait footer  { width: 768px; }

.page.portrait article .content_container { width: 768px; height: 919px; }

.page.portrait.home .engine_image { position: absolute; -webkit-transform: translate3d(550px,380px,0px); }
.page.portrait.home .commercial_image   { position: absolute; -webkit-transform: translate3d(350px,730px,0px); }
.page.portrait.home .military_image   { position: absolute; -webkit-transform: translate3d(430px,550px,0px); }
.page.portrait.home .uav_image  { position: absolute; -webkit-transform: translate3d(450px,150px,0px); }
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
        <link type="text/css" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="assets/images/template/icon.png?v=1" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="assets/images/template/startup_landscape.jpg?v=1" media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape)" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="assets/images/template/startup_portrait.jpg?v=1" media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait)" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/includes/bom.css?v=1" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/includes/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/includes/Iscroll4/iscroll.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/includes/bom.js?v=1"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page home">
            <footer></footer>
            <article>
                <div class="content_container">
                    <div class"content_loading_container"></div>
                </div>
            </article>
            <header></header>
            <img class="banner_logo" src="assets/images/template/logo.png?v=1" />
            <img class="engine_image" src="assets/images/template/engine.png?v=1" width="200" height="153" />           
            <img class="commercial_image" src="assets/images/template/A380.png?v=1" width="400" height="194" />         
            <img class="military_image" src="assets/images/template/f-35.png?v=1" width="300" height="157" />           
            <img class="uav_image" src="assets/images/template/uav.png?v=1" width="300" height="196" />
            <nav>
                <a data-file="engines.html?v=1"><img class="icon" src="assets/images/template/icon_engine.png?v=1" width="68" height="57" /></a> 
                <a data-file="general.bus.html?v=1"><img class="icon" src="assets/images/template/icon_gen.bus.png?v=1" width="68" height="57" /></a>
                <a data-file="helicopters.html?v=1"><img class="icon" src="assets/images/template/icon_helicopter.png?v=1" width="68" height="57" /></a>
                <a data-file="commercial.html?v=1"><img class="icon" src="assets/images/template/icon_commercial.png?v=1" width="68" height="57" /></a>
                <a data-file="military.html?v=1"><img class="icon" src="assets/images/template/icon_military.png?v=1" width="68" height="57" /></a>
                <a data-file="military.ground.html?v=1"><img class="icon" src="assets/images/template/icon_military-ground.png?v=1" width="68" height="57" /></a>
                <a data-file="missiles.html?v=1"><img class="icon" src="assets/images/template/icon_missile.png?v=1" width="68" height="57" /></a>
                <a data-file="regional.html?v=1"><img class="icon" src="assets/images/template/icon_regional.png?v=1" width="68" height="57"/></a>
                <a data-file="uav.html?v=1"><img class="icon" src="assets/images/template/icon_uav.png?v=1" width="68" height="57" /></a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why this anonymous down vote?

Comment: I didn't down vote but my guess is that the question is a wall of code with little mention of what debugging steps the asker has taken. Generally it is expected that the asker tries to narrow down the code a little more and ask a more specific question. That said the asker won't benefit from a downvote with no explanation.

Comment: What is a down vote? Thank you for not doing it though because it sounds negative. I will give more debugging details next time.

Comment: Not entirely related to the question, but loading whole pages via javascript is going to cause you a lot of SEO problems.

Comment: Thank you, Jason for letting me know. I was just trying to get as detailed as possible in the hopes of finding an solution to why my pages won't load. I'm new to this forum and guess I should have read the rules more carefully.

Comment: I have voted to close this question because it's too specific to your site, and unlikely to help any future visitors.  The best questions are free of errors / typos (try a code validator like http://validator.w3.org/) and contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'assets/content/'+fileName` shoudnt you change it to `'/assets/content/'+fileName`

also i could find an error in your html
`<div class"content_loading_container"></div>` should be `<div class="content_loading_container"></div>`

Comment: Thanks again, Parv. This didn't help.

Comment: try running this in an environment where you can debug it.. like a desktop and then see the errors you might be getting

Comment: I actually am just test in Safari on my Mac right now. I wanted to make sure it runs here before I tried testing on my iPad.                    (is that what you meant?)

Comment: yean that is what i mean. what errors are you seeing in the developer console??

Comment: Not one issue shows up in the developer console in Safari. Unless I'm not checking it correctly. But I've used it before and caught errors in my code. This is the first time I've written some custom JavaScript though.

Comment: check to see the request you are sending is being sent correctly and the data you are getting back in response in good

Comment: OH MY GOSH! That was it! Thank you, thank you, thank you! I was ready to throw in the towel.